# aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are: this is the error showing with some number of commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
aws rekognition index-faces \
--image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"mybucketname","Name":"S3ObjectKey"}}' \
--collection-id "image1" \
--region us-east-1 \
--profile adminuser
```

That is my code which I'm running on terminal, I tried but don't know why is that error coming. What changes should I do??

Comment: It sounds like you are running an old version of aws-cli.  Try checking `aws --version`.

Comment: yes got it..!!
I'm using old version thanks for the help.

Answer (score 21):

I ran into the same issue on a Mac. Looks like after successful:

```
pip install --user --upgrade awscli
```

"aws --version" was still pointing to the old version.

Running the following helped:

```
sudo -H pip install awscli --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```

Comment: Running these commands help `brew uninstall awscli `, `brew update`, `brew install awscli` in Macbook.